# Understanding Istanbul's code coverage

Tags: javascript, code-coverage, istanbul

I just started with an example file (example.js) which has the following statements:

```
x = 42;
if(false)
  x = -1;
```

I don't have any unit test file. but when I run

```
istanbul cover example.js
```

I see some the below coverage data

```
=============================== Coverage summary ===============================
Statements   : 66.67% ( 2/3 )
Branches     : 50% ( 1/2 )
Functions    : 100% ( 0/0 )
Lines        : 66.67% ( 2/3 )
==============================================================================
```

Does that imply I have 2 statements out of 3 that are covered?  If so, how can it report that this code is covered when I don't have any unit test file targeting that code?

From what I understand by definition of code coverage, it code that is covered by unit tests. I don't understand why istabul says that I have 2 statements covered when I have not written any unit tests.

Comment: 2 of the 3 statements will always execute and 1 will never execute.  This will be true no matter what test you run on the sample code provided.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Istanbul checks to see what lines of code were run.  Simply running the file will execute two of the lines, and ignoring the third.  If you were to create something like this:

```
module.exports = {
  myFunc: function() {
    x = 42;
    if(false) {
      x = -1;
    }
  }
};
```

You'd get a different result (`x = 42` wouldn't be run at all).  The one statement executed is `module.exports`

```
=============================== Coverage summary ===============================
Statements   : 25% ( 1/4 )
Branches     : 0% ( 0/2 )
Functions    : 0% ( 0/1 )
Lines        : 25% ( 1/4 )
================================================================================
```

Comment: when I just have function (not as variable assignment) why I still have statement coverage as 1? I don't have any statement which invokes the function.

Comment: @iRamesh The function declaration is run as part of running the file.

Comment: What does the branch statistic generate from?

Comment: @streetlight Branches are `if/else` or `switch` statements and the like.

Answer (score 1):

example.js suppose to be the test file. And if you want to include source code, run with `--include-all-sources`.